# How to prevent Subdivision Surface from changing the size of a loop

Tags: modeling, geometry, subdivision-surface

I modelled this hole but when I turn SS on, it becomes too small. Adding geometry around it isnt an option, since I want everything to be as smooth as possible. Scaling it up doesnt work, because this destroys the "normal" geometry.

[image: Blender hole]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rotate the hole 45° or create an hexagon: the diamond shape generate a smaller hole than the square/hexagon ones.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

add geometry around it but space it out properly. it'll be smooth as you want it with the right topology.

Comment: For me it still becomes that small, I even tried it with pure support loops, but this only resulted in a hard edge around the hole

Comment: screen shot of the unsmoothed? It should be the more geo you add, the more like the end shape it looks.

Comment: Additionally, for there to be a hard edge from your support loops means your support loops are going in the wrong direction.